# Web hook - get notified when my app is deleted from google third party apps

Tags: node.js, google-api, notifications, google-drive-api, webhooks

I have a Node JS app that uses google drive API to upload/import files.
The user have to provide permissions to my application in order to handle his files on his google drive.
When the user gives access to my app, it will appears on his third party apps on his google account.

After spending a lot of times scrolling in the google documentation, i couldn't find a solution for this problem:
How can my application receives a notification or a web hook request, when the user removes access to my application from his google account settings.
[image]

I hope that it's clear.
Thanks in advance.